# How to user orderBy and Paginate at the same time in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to paginate and order a list and it gave me error method orderby does not exist. Below is the code :

namespace App\Providers;

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Edisi;
use DB;
use View;

class EdisiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        View::composer(['edisi/index', 'pages/home'], function ($view) {
            $edisi_list = DB::table('edisi')->paginate(3)->orderBy('id')->get();
            $view->with('edisi_list', $edisi_list);
        });
    }
    public function register() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to call `orderBy()` before paginating the results (You also don't need to call `get()` either).

So you would have:

```
$edisi_list = DB::table('edisi')->orderBy('id')->paginate(3);
```